# jQuery binding issue

Tags: jquery, binding

```
function addFav(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/favorites/add",
      data: {"id": articleID},
      success: function(){
           $('a#fav')
                 .addClass('active')
                 .attr('title','[-] Remove as favorite')
                 .unbind('click')
                 .bind('click','removeFav')
           ;
      }
    });
}

function removeFav(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/favorites/remove",
      data: {"id": articleID},
      success: function(){
            $('a#fav')
                 .removeClass('active')
                 .attr('title','[+] Add as favorite')
                 .unbind('click')
                 .bind('click','addFav')
            ;
      }
    });
}

$('a#fav').bind('click','addFav');
```

This is what i have right now.
Nothing happens when i click on a#fav, is it because i need to wrap it in a document.ready?
I tried that, but then i get a error, from the jQuery library?? in firebug

```
d is undefined
Line 49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the function (and not a string) as the second parameter to `bind`, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', addFav);
});
```

Be sure to do that within your `$(document).ready(...` as in the above example, and remember to fix the `bind` calls within both of your functions.

Comment: +1 - Should add that he *does* need a `document.ready`, if it takes that to get the error and he isn't getting one currently :)